# Extracting column from Array in python

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am beginner in Python and I am stuck with data which is array of 32763 number, separated by comma. Please find the data here [data](http://data-file)

I want to convert this into two column 1 from (0:16382) and 2nd column from (2:32763). in the end I want to plot column 1 as x axis and column 2 as Y axis. I tried the following code but I am not able to extract the columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('oscilloscope.txt',delimiter=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data.flatten())
print(df)
```

and then I want to write the data in some file let us say data1 in the format as shown in attached pic [image: data for]

Comment: I can't write an answer right now but you could just split on your input string, then create the data frame with two columns using the array. You can use range (0:16382) on the array in order to define want is the content of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer without seeing the format of your data, but you can try

```
data = np.genfromtxt('oscilloscope.txt',delimiter=',')
print(data.shape) # here we check we got something useful

# this should split data into x,y at position 16381
x = data[:16381]
y = data[16381:]


# now you can create a dataframe and print to file
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
df.to_csv('data1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: so it should work except 32763 is an odd number and you need x,y to be of the same length. how do you want to deal with that?

Comment: It was mistake from my side. I made it to read the x upto 16381 than this  works. I wanted to write this into file again, so I wrote something like this  (which is not writnf anything)                                 time = str(x)
ch1data = str(y)
file = open("oscilloscope1.txt","w")
file.write(time+ "\t" + ch1data)
file.close

Comment: looks ok-ish except you probably want `file.close()` (note the parenthesis). This should write to a file but may not be in the format you want. how do you want it in the file? please provide a snippet of you desired output

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have modified my question for the format

Comment: and I modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

#input as dataframe df, its chunk_size, extract output as list. you can mention chunksize what you want.

```
def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size = 16382): 
    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
    chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
return chunks
```

or

```
np.array_split
```